# Why does Clifford D. Simak's "Construction Shack" end so abruptly?

Tags: clifford-d-simak

Clifford D. Simak's "[Construction Shack](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54512)" is a 1973 short story, available in various places online and [on archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=simak%20%22construction%20shack%22), covering a manned expedition to Pluto where they discover evidence that the solar system was constructed, possibly badly. In my mind, the story ends very abruptly, and I can't tell if it was supposed to be because something happened, or because Simak just wanted to leave us with a slice of life regarding the mystery.

> I tried to envision it. A construction shack set down in a cloud of dust and gas. Engineers who may have worked for millennia to put together star and planets, to key into them certain factors that still would be at work, billions of years later.
>
> Tyler said they had bungled and perhaps they had. But maybe not with Venus. Maybe Venus had been built to different specifications. Maybe it had been designed to be the way it was. Perhaps, a billion years from now, when humanity might well be gone from Earth, a new life and a new intelligence would rise on Venus.
>
> Maybe not with Venus, maybe with none of the others, either. We could not pretend to know.
>
> Tyler was still going through the sheets.
>
> "Look here," he was yelling. "Look here, the bunglers—"

Was there any contemporary review, maybe with input from Simak, indicating why it ends in the middle of a statement?

Comment: IMHO nothing happened at the end, just that the 2nd guy continued to yell about what he saw.  It will be interesting to see if this gets a sourced answer.

Comment: It was a one-trick story. It delivered on the punchline. What else was there to say that would have made the story stronger rather than weaker?

Comment: It's not so much that there was more to say as that ending the story mid-sentence like that is usually significant in and of itself, indicating that someone was cut off by an event. The use of a long dash might be what's throwing me off, since it's used for everything from a pause (much like a common use of ellipsis) to a sudden interruption to the beginning of a parenthetical. To me, this reads as Tyler getting cut off.

Comment: @NomadMaker has it exactly right. *I* have known plenty of techies who would have reacted that way about near God-like aliens and I expect Simak had, also. I'll bet he listened to someone just like that and thought, "I can make a great short story out of that!" And did. It was a brilliant story in an admittedly small way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't read this as suggesting that something suddenly happened to the crew.  The story is clearly being *related* by Hunt; besides the first-person viewpoint, the part where he explains their feelings feels retrospective and doesn't really fit with a story that's taking place at the moment it is being told:

> It isn't homesickness that you feel.  It's more like never having had a home.  Of never having belonged anywhere.  You get over it, of course—or come to live with it.

Further confirmation that the crew survived is that the narrator mentions events that followed the story, that must have followed the crew's return to the Moon:

> On the first sheet were diagrams of some sort, drawings and what might have been specifications written into the diagrams and along the margins.  The specifications, of course, meant nothing to us (**although later some were puzzled out and mathematicians and chemists were able to figure out some of the formulas and equations**).

I think this is being cut off because the author is allowing us to imagine what the next blunder might have been.  It would be very hard to top the construction crew messing up the orbits of Uranus and Neptune, the biosphere of Mars and the *entire 5th planet*, so Simak doesn't even try.